# What is the correct preposition to use for adding a product {on/in/at} a website?

Tags: prepositions

How is it correct to say:

> What do you think about adding "NameOfProduct" **on** ProductHunt.com?

I never know if I should use on / in / at.

Comment: This question can be reopened after you clarify what "ProductHunt" is. (I can't tell if it's a game, an application, a class in an object-oriented design, or something else.)

Comment: ProductHunt is actually the name of a website. While I agree the OP should make that clear, I think a quick Google would have revealed it.

Comment: @SamBC Questions should be clear without a Google search. How do you know the author is talking about the website and not the app or the API for it? I edited the title to reflect “website” but I would like that to be confirmed by the author before taking the question off hold

Comment: @ColleenV Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ProductHunt is some sort of collection or catalogue, but the key here is that you are using ***add***. Most of the time with *add*, the right preposition is ***to***. You particularly *add* something *to* a list, or catalogue, or collection. If you used *put* instead of *add*, then *on* or *in* might be appropriate.

On the other hand, ***on*** might be seen as appropriate because the *act* of adding would might be done "on the website". By the same token, ***in*** might be appropriate if the *act* of adding would done "in the app". ***To***, however, is safe as long as the audience understands that ProductHunt is a collection or catalogue.